# How to Restrict AWS AMI access to certain user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I just have created an AWS EC2 AMI for my EC2 instance.
I wanted to give restriction to that AMI(user level,not account level).
For example User1 have created AMI named ami-123.
User1,User2,User3 are present in that account.
I want only User1 should have permission to create EC2 instance using ami-123.

Please help me to sort it out?

Comment: you can add an `explicit deny` inline policy to the other users from `RunInstances` with resource condition being the image ARN.

Answer (score 4):

By default, users in an AWS Account have **no permissions** to do anything.

You then grant them permissions for actions they are **allowed to call**, such as `RunInstances`.

As part of these permissions, you can **restrict the permissions they are receiving**, such as the AMI they can specify:

```
arn:aws:ec2:region::image/*
```

See: [Resource-Level Permissions for RunInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html#supported-iam-actions-runinstances)

Alternatively, you could ALLOW `RunInstances` but then create a policy to DENY use of a particular AMI.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Actually in my scenario,all other users have full access to EC2 instance.What i need to do in that case?

Comment: You would create a DENY policy for `RunInstances` with the AMI specified, which you would apply against all people you do *not* wish to have access to the AMI. This way, you are granting them *all* permissions, but then explicitly denying them this permission. You need to do it against the users, not the AMI.